# Rake error: Permission denied - c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/data

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I had a basic copy function working, but I extended it to handle sub directories when passed ancestors and now receive an error.

```
def copy_to(dest, src)

    files = FileList.new()
    EXT_ALLOWED.each {|ext| files.include "#{src}/**/*.#{ext}"}
    files.each do |file|
        dir = File.dirname(file)
        filename = File.basename(file)
        path = dir.match(/shared\/(.*)/)
        if dest == path[1] + '/'
            bin = dest
        else
            bin = File.join(dest, path[1] + '/')
        end
        puts "copying #{filename} to #{bin}"
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(bin)
        FileUtils.cp src, bin
    end

end
```

Here is how I am calling the function:

```
task :ui_gateway do
  copy_to 'static/', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/css'
  copy_to 'static/', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/fonts'
  copy_to 'static/', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/images'
  copy_to 'static/', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/lib'
  copy_to 'static/', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/scripts'
  copy_to 'ui/', 'c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/ui'
end
```

The complete `--trace`:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\home\app\gateway>rake ui_gateway --trace                       
(in C:/xampp/htdocs/home/app/gateway)                                              
** Invoke ui_gateway (first_time)                                                                 
** Execute ui_gateway                                                                             
copying controls.css to static/css/                                                            
rake aborted!                                                                                         
Permission denied - c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/css                                
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1265:in `initialize'                                           
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1265:in `copy_stream'                                          
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1265:in `block in copy_file'                                   
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1264:in `open'                                                 
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1264:in `copy_file'                                            
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:471:in `copy_file'                                             
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:392:in `block in cp'                                           
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1396:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'                            
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1410:in `fu_each_src_dest0'                                    
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1394:in `fu_each_src_dest'                                     
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:391:in `cp'                                                    
C:/xampp/htdocs/home/fugrosdes/src/oars/app/gateway/rakefile.rb:34:in `block in copy_to'              
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1248:in `each'                                                      
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1248:in `each'                                                      
C:/xampp/htdocs/home/fugrosdes/src/oars/app/gateway/rakefile.rb:23:in `copy_to'                       
C:/xampp/htdocs/home/fugrosdes/src/oars/app/gateway/rakefile.rb:62:in `block in <top (required)>'     
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:613:in `call'                                                       
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:613:in `block in execute'                                           
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:608:in `each'                                                       
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:608:in `execute'                                                    
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:574:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'                            
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:190:in `mon_synchronize'                                         
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:567:in `invoke_with_call_chain'                                     
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:560:in `invoke'                                                     
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2012:in `invoke_task'                                               
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1990:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'                             
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1990:in `each'                                                      
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1990:in `block in top_level'                                        
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2029:in `standard_exception_handling'                               
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1984:in `top_level'                                                 
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1963:in `block in run'                                              
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2029:in `standard_exception_handling'                               
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1960:in `run'                                                       
C:/Ruby191/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

The goal is to have a directory created in the destination directory which matches the directory(s) in the source. If the destination is `static` and the source is `c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/css` the resulting destination should be `static/css/`. Then the files from the shared directories would be copied to the destination. If the source has sub-directories they would need to be created as well and the `dir.match()` function seems to be getting the information required.

**EDIT** Added the following line if the `if` condition to make the appropriate directories and subs -

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(bin)
```

This *does* create the appropriate directories and subs if I comment out the line which is suppose to perform the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file utilities in Ruby / Rake require that you are very specific about files in order to operate on them. In the original code `src` only refers to the path (2nd argument) sent to the `copy_to` function. The file names, as part of those paths, is not retrieved until the `files.each` loop:

```
files.each do |file|
```

At *this* point `file` contains the full path to the file as well as the file name. This is what must be the first argument in the copy function:

```
FileUtils.cp file, bin
```

***PRIOR*** to attempting to copy any files all of the directories must be in place or you will get a different error:

> copying c:/xampp/htdocs/home/shared/css/controls.css to static/css/
>
> rake aborted!
> Invalid argument - static/css/

Creating the new directories is done by adding the following line to the `copy_to` function just after the `if` condition:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(bin)
```

This creates the directory if it does not exist, which then allows the file to be copied into it.

***Suggestion for improvement*** - It seems inefficient to try the `mkdir_p` on every file, rewrite this such that the directories are checked and then created if need be. (The additional overhead *might* not be worth an extra check, worth exploring.)